# Expression Trees Conversion

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have two Classes :

```
class Customer
{
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class CustomerDTO
{
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

now i have an expressiontree `Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expression` Passed between layers , can i convert it to `Expression<Func<CustomerDTO, bool>> expression` to be able to use it since it would give compile time error!

thanks in advance

Comment: Any chance you can use an Interface instead of the class? No idea myself, just a suggestion.

Comment: i.e. `Expression<Func<ICustomer, bool>> expression` Customer and CustomerDTO then implement that interface.

Comment: i cant do that because that cause the first class is generated i can force it to implement an interface!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind i made it

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expression = v => v.Fullname == "Johm";
         var par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CustomerDTO));
         Expression<Func<CustomerDTO, bool>> ex = (Expression<Func<CustomerDTO, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(expression.Body, par);
```

Comment: Nice, now just accept your own answer so it gets removed from the queue. :)

Comment: While your solution would works and I know you said you didn't want to use interfaces, typically a code generator these days generates code as partial classes.  You add a partial class part to the same class where you implement the interface (so the other partial part can be blown away on the next regen).  Then you could use `Expression<Func<IEntity, bool>>`